# React js: how to draw svg into a canvas that doesn't exist yet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas, svg

I have a `render()` function that's rendering my React component, and I want to include a `<canvas>` that has some SVG rendered onto it, as in [this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/1m0nxe4c/8/) However, I can't include that js in the `return` of the render function, so I'm attempting to return the canvas element from a function I made that's supposed to create it, then attach the svg. This is what I have:

```js
getEditionCircle: function(result) {
   var canvas = <canvas id="can" width="37" height="37"/>
          
        // all the code in the fiddle to render the svg
          
        return canvas;
}

render: function() {
     
    return (
      <div className={bemBlocks.item().mix(bemBlocks.container("item"))}>
         <span className='counterBadge'>{result._source.length}</span>
  <div>{this.getEditionCircle(result)}</div>
        <img className='gridImg'
              style={{height: 311}}
              src={imgUrl}/>
     </div>
 )
}
```

Right now when I run it, it says `canvas.getContext is not a function` which makes sense to me, since the canvas isn't rendered yet.

edit: Two things that are relevant; I have to pass data to this svg generator (hence the `results` parameter), and this is part of a component that will be repeated multiple times on one page, so there will be multiple `canvas` elements that have to be rendered to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a DOM element after React has created it, use `ref` or `onRef`, [explained here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Since you want to use the element as soon as it is created, use `onRef`:

```
drawOnCanvas: function(canvas) {
    if (!canvas) {
        return; // Should not happen, but do check anyway
    }

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    // the rest of the code in the fiddle to render the svg
}

render: function() {
    return (
        <div className={bemBlocks.item().mix(bemBlocks.container("item"))}>
            <span className='counterBadge'>{result._source.length}</span>
            <canvas onRef={this.drawOnCanvas} width="37" height="37" />
            <img
                className='gridImg'
                style={{height: 311}}
                src={imgUrl}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: For some reason, I always get `canvas` as undefined. Also I had to use `onRef={this.drawOnCanvas()}` instead of the syntax you gave since it was complaining about `drawOnCanvas` being undefined, and without the brackets it never got called at all.

Comment: Ah, you found a bug in my answer. It should be `onRef={this.drawOnCanvas}`. I've updated the answer. *Note:* Don't call the method directly like described in your comment (leave out the `()`).

Comment: I also need to pass params to the `drawOnCanvas` function; is there a way of doing that?

Comment: If you `.bind(this)` to `onRef={this.drawOnCanvas.bind(this)}`, then drawOnCanvas has access to the component instance via `this`. So you can access `this.props` or `this.state` inside `drawOnCanvas`. Note that `onRef` is only called once, so if you need to re-render `drawOnCanvas` you need to trigger it somehow. Another way is to `.bind(this, arg1, arg2)`, then it will be called with arguments `arg1` and `arg2`.

Comment: Your answer needed to be slightly modified for it to work for me; it's `ref` not `onRef`. Apart from that, it works, thanks :)

Comment: Hm, small issue; I called it with `.bind(this, source)` where `source` is a chunk of data I need to send, but it sent the data instead of the canvas object as the first parameter. The second parameter was null.

Comment: Yeah, for what you're trying to achieve here I don't think you should bind after all. Where does source come from? Props?

Comment: Ah, it's fine now, it's a prop so I can access it through the new function too. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error is arising as the `canvas` element with id `can` has not been rendered yet. Here is what you should do:

Put the canvas directly in the DOM. Don't put it as a function that returns the canvas (which is what you are doing now)

```
render: function() {

    return (
         <div className={bemBlocks.item().mix(bemBlocks.container("item"))}>
         <span className='counterBadge'>{result._source.length}</span>
         <div>
            <canvas id="can" width="37" height="37"/>
         </div>
         <img className='gridImg' style={{height: 311}} src={imgUrl}/>
         </div>
    )
}
```

Use the `componentDidMount` function to perform the manipulation of the canvas. The `componentDidMount` even is fired after mounting (ie conversion of JSX to HTML) but before the rendering.

```
componentDidMount: function(){
    //all the code in the fiddle
}
```

Comment: Technically that worked. But I forgot to add two important conditions; I need to pass params to the function that generates the svg, and there are going to be multiple canvas elements per page. Right now it's only generating the svg on the first canvas element, which makes sense, since it'll get the first one it sees.

Comment: Could you describe in a bit more detail? Are the number of canvases fixed per page? What are the params you need to pass to the function (just a general idea)?

If the number of canvases are fixed you can hardcode them all with separate ids and in the `componentDidMount` call the function with different params. A more detailed idea would allow me to help you better.

Comment: There's one canvas per component, but there could be hundreds of components per page. The params are pretty simple, basically an array of  four fields that's used to render the specific svg.

Is there a way to have something like an `svg` element that gets rendered directly/immediately in the `render` function, instead of having  a canvas selected from the document and then have svg on top of it? I realise that that's not exactly an ideal solution when it comes to react.

Comment: The problem with the canvas manipulation here is that they all have the same id so every component fires that method in the `componentDidMount` but all target the first element. What you can do is use props to ensure the ids are different. So in the parent page for each component do something like `<Component id={i} />` where `i` is some counter or something for unique ids.

Inside the `render` function of the component do 

`<canvas id={this.props.id} width="37" height="37/>`

and inside the `componentDidMount` function do

`var canvas = document.getElementById(this.props.id);`

Comment: Also you can pass the params (which I am guessing are determined in the main page) as props to the components and inside the component `componentDidMountFunction` access these props for rendering the SVG. This is similar to how the `id` is passed as a prop and used by the Component.